# set data attribute to html elements from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have the following html structure

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">one</div>
        <div class="cell">two</div>
        <div class="cell">three</div> 
        <div class="cell">four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">one</div>
        <div class="cell">two</div>
        <div class="cell">three</div> 
        <div class="cell">four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">one</div>
        <div class="cell">two</div>
        <div class="cell">three</div> 
        <div class="cell">four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">one</div>
        <div class="cell">two</div>
        <div class="cell">three</div> 
        <div class="cell">four</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to loop through each of the "cell' class and set data attribute from an array of strings.

For ex. `["a", "b", "c", "d" ...]`

The number of "cell" elements and number of elements in the array will always be the same

Expected output should be

```
<div class="main">
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell" data-label="a">one</div>
    <div class="cell" data-label="b">two</div>
    <div class="cell" data-label="c">three</div> 
    <div class="cell" data-label="d">four</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell" data-label="a">one</div>
    <div class="cell" data-label="b">two</div>
    <div class="cell" data-label="c">three</div> 
    <div class="cell" data-label="d">four</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell" data-label="a">one</div>
    <div class="cell" data-label="b">two</div>
    <div class="cell" data-label="c">three</div> 
    <div class="cell" data-label="d">four</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell" data-label="a">one</div>
    <div class="cell" data-label="b">two</div>
    <div class="cell" data-label="c">three</div> 
    <div class="cell" data-label="d">four</div>
</div>    
</div>
```

I was able to loop through "rows" and convert it to an array of arrays and then got stuck on how to set data-attributes from another array. Do we need to iterate through each of "cell" elements in the ""row" and convert it into array or can we pass the data attribute through any other approach.

```
let phrases = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
const rows = document.querySelectorAll(".row");
let cellArray = []
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const cells = rows[i].querySelectorAll(".cell")
    cellArray.push(cells)
}
for (let j = 0; j < cellArray.length; j++) {
    var value = parent[j];

    for (let k = 0; k < parent[j].length; k++) {
        var innerValue = parent[j][k];
    }
}
```

Comment: The `parent` variable appears to be undefined.  And the array `phrases` is never referenced. Are you using `parent` when you should be using `phrases`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below logic, it might help you.

```
const rows = document.querySelectorAll(".row");
let phrases = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].querySelectorAll(".cell");
    console.log(cells.length);
    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
        cells[j].setAttribute('data-label', phrases[j]); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

something like that ?

```
const phrases = 'abcd';

document.querySelectorAll('div.row').forEach( row => 
  {
  row.querySelectorAll('div.cell').forEach((cell,i) => cell.dataset.label = phrases[i])
  })
```